# SharePoint 2010 - How to add custom button to DispForm

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation

I am attempting to add a label, text box and a button to dispform page. The purpose is for a user looking at a list entry to add a comment. Upon clicking on the button, the text they entered will update another list.

Is is possible to do this and how?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I want to thank you for your suggestions.  What I ended up doing was something quite similar to the steps given on The SharePoint Dive for customizing list forms.  You can find the steps here:

http://thesharepointdive.wordpress.com/2012/03/20/list-forms-deployment-for-sharepoint-2010-part-1-of-4/

It was a bit more work than your suggestions may have been but fit my requirements quite well and something I can easily re-use in other solutions.

Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way would to put a button on the Ribbon that pops up a modal dialog containing your label, text box and submit/cancel buttons. You could do this using a Custom Action.

Now, if that doesn't meet your requirements, then I would probably look next at writing a form template for that content type's display form. You could add a control that encapsulates the functionality you require to the template.

Comment: Hello, this sounds like the best solution, but I must admit it is not something that I have done before.  I don't suppose you happen to have some snippets I can see as an example.  I understand how to add a custom action to a dispform.aspx, but not how to customize it to provide a window to update another list.  Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can customized the existing display form, by just adding a new web part to the page. So you compose your new functionality to a separate web part and then you add it to the existing display form (top or bottom as you need) by doing that you can get this achieved.